# Lotus Notes - exclude current document from embedded view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have an embedded view from which I would like to exclude the current document. Is there a way of doing this? The view selection is correct and displays a number of documents which include the document which contains the embedded view (which I would like to exclude).

Comment: In XPages you can...

Comment: unfortunately I must solve this in the Notes client

Comment: One other way, but it might be sluggishly slow: use a Folder, copy all documents in the view to the folder, except for the document currently open, and display the folder...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you have no chance to exclude the current document from your embedded view because the only choice you have is to show a **single category** in an embedded view.

A workaround could be to prevent the current document from opening:

```
Sub Queryopendocument(Source As Notesuiview, Continue As Variant)
    Dim docs As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Set docs = Source.Documents
    Set doc = docs.GetFirstDocument

    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace

    If doc.UniversalID = ws.CurrentDocument.Document.UniversalID Then
        Continue = False
    End If

End Sub
```

I hope this helps :)